# Attach to and debug an already running Ruby script on Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, debugging

I'm on Linux with a Ruby script running in a terminal window (it sits in a while loop with some sleep timeout, and does work when something changes.)

The problem is, occasionally the script seems to freeze and stop responding. A typical scenario is if I leave it sitting overnight.

If I break and restart it, the script works fine.

So, **1)** is there a way to attach to this already-running ruby script's interpreter to find out where it's getting stuck? Ideally I'd get a stack trace.

If not possible on-the-fly, **2)** how can I run it so that next time it freezes I can get a stack?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are likely better "ruby ways" to solve this problem. But doing a google search on [attach to a running ruby process](https://www.google.com/search?q=attach+to+running+ruby+process) turned up a blog post  with some helpful suggestions for using gdb to debug a live Ruby process on Linux: [Tools for Debugging Running Ruby Processes](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/08/19/debug-ruby-processes/). This further linked to [another blog post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/9/22/inspecting-a-live-ruby-process) with some useful information on using gdb to get a ruby stack trace:

1. Find the PID of your ruby script, e.g.

   ```
   ps aux | grep -i <script_name.rb>
   ```
2. Attach to it with gdb:

   ```
   sudo gdb `which ruby` <pid>
   ```
3. Run these commands in gdb to get the Ruby backtrace:

   ```
   (gdb) set $ary = (int)backtrace(-1)
   (gdb) set $count = *($ary+8)
   (gdb) set $index = 0
   (gdb) while $index < $count
   >  x/1s *((int)rb_ary_entry($ary, $index)+12)
   >  set $index = $index + 1
   >end
   ```

This got me close, but gdb encountered an error while loading ruby symbols, and another error trying to run the `backtrace` function. I'll update this answer as I figure out more. Feel free to make other suggestions.

- The blogpost also links an interesting set of [gdb recipes](https://github.com/michaelklishin/gdb-macros-for-ruby/blob/master/gdb_macros_for_ruby) for debugging Ruby.